# Selenium wait until all specified web elements are changed or gone

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Suppose there is a HTML block

```
<div id='list'>
   <p>hello</p>
   <div class='locked'>world</div>
   <p>你好</p>
   <div class='locked'>世界</div>
</div>
```

how to use selenium with python to wait for a while until **all** the `<div class='locked'>` tags become something else.(eg.  `<div class='unlock'>xxx</div>`

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, please tell what have you tried and what language do you use?

Comment: I am using python. I tried "WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located) " , but this is only for one element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One could write a custom expected condition checking for the specific state that you need to attain. Like in your scenario you want the controls with locked state or class to be at count 0 to proceed further. I have given a sample of the code that could be used for custom Sync function
I am new to python based Selenium but it think this should do the trick assuming you are using xpath for identifying the locked state controls.

--------------Updated with Python Code---------------------------

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class WaitForLockStateChange:
def __init__(self, locator):
    self.locator = locator

def __call__(self, driver):
    return len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(self.locator)) == 0 


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(WaitForLockStateChange("//div[@class='locked']"))
```

Comment: Could you write in python please? I am not familar with Java.. But the idea to check the count of elements sounds good. I will have a try first.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a custom built class I created for a very similar purpose (in my case I was interested in "value" property changes, but I modified it to fit your "class" change example):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class WaitForAttrValueChange:
    def __init__(self, locator, val_):
        self.locator = locator
        self.val = val_

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            attr_value = EC._find_element(driver, self.locator).get_property('className')
            return attr_value.startswith(self.val)
        except SE.StaleElementReferenceException:
            return False
```

You can then use it with `WebDriverWait`(obviously you can use any `By` identification method instead of `By.ID`, this is just an example):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(WaitForAttrValueChange((By.ID, 'id'), 'locked'))
```

Comment: But this seems only to detect one web element.

Comment: Loop through all the divs you need checking. Update your question with how you identify **all** elements in scope please, and I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Loop through all the divs and check it one by one should also be good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) with [python](/questions/tagged/python) to wait for all the `<div class='locked'>` tags become `<div class='unlock'>xxx</div>` you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#list div.unlock")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='list']//div[@class='unlock']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: This won't work because if only one element currently matches `div.unlock` then the wait will end. OP is asking about how to detect that there are 0 `div.lock` elements.